# Customization of Dynamics GP

Tags: dynamics-gp

I'm trying to customize the Dynamics GP using the Visual Studio. I got the VS Tools SDK installed on my system, But i'm unable to find  the dynamics gp icon in the project templates.
How should integrate the VS Tools SDK with the VS 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the SDK, and carefully read the Visual Studio versions. You won't get the templates on any version of VS after the GP date. In other words, for GP 2016, you have to use VS 2015 or earlier

http://dynDeveloper.com/Article/FD27